# I am trying to run a query that takes value from one table and uses it as condition to fetch value or execute action on another table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to take the value of the topay column where torecieve equals to current session user id and use it to perform operation on the user table.

But it throws a syntax error

```
 <?php
 session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "bazze2";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$merge = "SELECT topay FROM merge WHERE torecieve=$_SESSION[id]";

$sql = "UPDATE user SET topay2='10000000' WHERE 'id'=$merge";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: brackets around the $merge query

Comment: `topay` and `toreceive` are ids? I think you need to have `{ }` around `$_SESSION[id]` to embed it in a string. You should actually use bind variables to reduce the risk of SQL injection. Furthermore `id` is probably a field name and shouldn't be quoted, and any subselect should be in parenthesis. All in all there is a significant number of minor errors and very little information for us to help you (like the exact error you're getting). I think you should just try a little more.

Comment: Why do you have the `pdo` tag when you're using `mysqli`?

Answer (score 1):

Use a prepared query, and use a join.

```
$sql = "UPDATE user AS u
        JOIN merge AS m ON u.id = m.topay
        SET u.topay2 = '10000000'
        WHERE m.toreceive = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['id']);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $stmt->error;
}
```